# Installable trigger not getting created

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

Newbie question about installable triggers: I have a Google form which stores responses in a worksheet. I have a script bound to the worksheet where I want to do some manipulation of the responses and send an email to the form submitter. My test 'onForumSubmit' function works correctly (sends an email) when I execute in the editor, however the trigger does not appear in the Triggers list, and my function does not execute when a new form is submitted. What am I missing?

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log('Hello World');
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "me@xyz.org",
    subject: "Testing",
    htmlBody: "This is a test email"
    });
}

function createFormSubmitTrigger(e) {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit")
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An [installable "on form submit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers) only needs to be created one time. Once it is in place, it will run whenever a form response is submitted.

The `createFormSubmitTrigger()` function you quote creates a trigger for a *form*. You are saying that the script project is bound to a spreadsheet, so that code will not work as is, because you need a trigger for a *spreadsheet*. There is an "on form submit" trigger for both kinds of files, but they require different creation code, and will run with a different event object `e`.

Since the trigger only needs to be created once, the easiest way to create it is to do it manually as shown in the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

Comment: Thanks - I changed to the spreadsheet version and now my "onFormSubmit" function executes as expected.

I'm aware that running my script in the editor creates multiple triggers, however I understood that functions requiring permissions (like MailApp.sendEmail) would only work with installable triggers.

Comment: _MailApp.sendEmail would only work with installable triggers_ That is correct, but nothing prevents you from creating an installable trigger manually. If you choose to create a trigger programmatically, only run the trigger installation code one time.

Comment: To clarify: the 'add trigger' menu option only supports predefined options. Would I need the trigger creation script unbound from the worksheet so I won't create a new trigger every time I test my other functions?

Comment: Those "predefined options" are the same regardless of whether you create a trigger manually or programmatically. What you need to do is to create exactly one trigger. I would recommend that you do it manually, since there is no obvious benefit to doing it programmatically. It is irrelevant whether you delete the `createFormSubmitTrigger(e)` function from your script project, as long as you only run it once, or not at all.